# Make the content of the json file vertically

Tags: python, json

```
time = [0 1 2 3....]
result = ['normal','limp'....]
def create_dict(a_number):
    return {'Time': time[a_number],
            'Reusult of this person': result[a_number]}
n = 0
final_dict = []
while n < len(time):
    dict = create_dict(n)
    final_dict.append(dict)
    n = n + 1
json_file = json.dumps(final_dict)
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_file)
```

I created n dictionary within a while loop then append them together, after generating json file, the dict in this file look as one long row,([{"Time": "0 seconds to 2", "Reusult of this person": "limp"}, {"Time": "1 seconds to 3", "Reusult of this person": "normal"}, {"Time": "2 secon) how to change it vertically?
[origin json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L780.png)

[vertical json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgmK6.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "change it vertically"?

Comment: use `json.dumps(final_dict, indent=2)` or some number. Note, you can skip `json_file = json.dumps(final_dict)` altogether and just do `with open("sample.json") as outfile: json.dump(final_dict, outfile, indent=2)` i.e., you don't need an intermediate string object, so don't use `json.dumps`, dump to a file object directly using `json.dump`